# Is there any way to store my app data (Sqlite) locally and i can access that data after my app is deleted or reinstalled?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, ios6

I am facing some issue in my application regarding storage, i wanna store my app data locally in iPad and it can be accessible after deleting the app or app reinstalled . i wanna send my old app data after reinstalling the app.
is there any approach so that i can implement it ?

Comment: As an app user, I certainly hope this functionality *doesn't* exist. When I delete an app, I expect it to be gone.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart true !! but i am looking for any alternative ,that can help me to get my old data :(

Comment: Thats what cloud, sync, data back up etc is for. It cannot be done locally on the same device.

Comment: If you are using CoreData and iCloud you can have your data stored locally while also being available in the cloud for re-download after uninstalling / re-installing. You will need to read the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH1-SW1) and code the option that works best for you. Keychain survives uninstallation but is only useful for small amounts of data. Alternatively, you could operate your own server and send data to the client for local caching on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Items in the keychain are kept even after your app is deleted, so you could store your data there, and retrieve it on re-install. Don't misuse it though, as keychain's main purpose is to store sensitive data like passwords, auth tokens etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to persist data **locally** even when app is removed is using a keychain. While I'm not sure about size limits and stuff. And, for sure, there some other ways with jailbroken devices.